# What is a better way to lazy load content for users with javascript?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, graceful-degradation, noscript

I have a page that has lots of images and other code that would work better if it is lazy loaded.

I have been attempting to do this with the noscript tag but I just noticed that it is not working correctly in IE.  It works in every other browser I tested (ff,opera,chrome,safari,etc) so I am a little frustrated.

I am pretty sure at one point or another I actually had this working in IE because I have been using the technique for a little while and I test IE quite frequently... but it isn't working now and everything I google seems to suggest that it never worked.

Here is a simple example to copy and paste that shows what I was attempting:

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Strict//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-strict.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" xml:lang="en" lang="en">
 <head>
  <title>lazy load with noscript</title>
  <script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.4.2/jquery.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>  
 </head>
 <body>

  <noscript>
   <div>
    <p>other content here</p>
    <img src="http://www.google.com/images/logos/ps_logo.png" alt="lazy loading image test" />
   </div>
  </noscript>

  <noscript>
   <div>
    <p>other content here 2</p>
    <img src="http://www.google.com/images/logos/ps_logo2.png" alt="lazy loading image test 2" />
   </div>
  </noscript>

  <script type="text/javascript">
   var html = $("noscript:first").text();
   alert(html);
   $("body").append(html);
  </script>

 </body>
</html>
```

The html used for users with javascript and without javascript is the same.  I just use jquery to tab the content to make it easier to view.  Since the content is tabbed in javascript it needs to lazy load when a tab opens so it does not take ages to download initially when the page has sizable attachments.

How can I achieve this without outputting the html more than once?

Comment: It would seem that IE doesn't add noscript tags to the dom if script is enabled. See: http://www.tjs.co.uk/blog/a-tale-of-accessibility-internet-explorer-and-the-noscript-tag.htm

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What you need to do is have all the images point to a pixel gif (or png). Write a script that checks if a user has scrolled near an image, and then use Javascript to swap the pixel with the full image.

In scripts I have written, you would have an image tag that looks like:

```
<img src="pixel.gif" data-img="path-to-full-img.jpg" />
```

Alternately, you could use a [plugin like this](https://github.com/jney/jquery_lazyload). Note: I have not used this plugin before, but it looks like it's all you need.

If you really wanted to get hardcore, you could lazyload your javascript using something like h[ead.js](http://headjs.com/) or [control.js](http://stevesouders.com/controljs/)

Comment: I just updated the question to demonstrate that the content is not only images.  I am using javascript to break the content into tabs that the user can click to see sections of content.  I do not think using 1px images is a good idea for this situation because if the user does not have javascript I want them to still be able to see everything, just the page will be very long and take a little longer to download.

Comment: Then in that case you should make an ajax request to get content for the tabs. Instead of using noscript, why don't you make the content look good without javascript, and then have javascript put a class on the containing element that gives it the style of tabs?

Comment: Well that is basically what I am doing.  The html used for javascript and noscript is the same, just the css style is just different.  Using the noscript tag allows me to do lazy loading where the browser does not render any content (fetch images, run flash, etc) before the tab is opened with javascript.  Since the html is already available I was really hoping to avoid having to write it out twice on the server side with ajax requests.  Is there no way to get around generating the page multiple times for a user with javascript?  I liked cutting the http requests down to one for all content.

Comment: You shouldn't use noscript at all for this. Make the content usable without JS, then use JS to enhance the experience (exactly what you're trying to do). By doing it this way you wont have to rewrite anything.